# youtube popup ran insecure content

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good day,

I have a popup where i used youtube pop
http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery_youtube/

The thing is that all was working good on IE, Chrome, firefox, opera

but now i have this error and all browsers stopped working except IE.

```
[blocked] The page at ../test.jsp ran insecure content from http://www.youtube.com/embed/BM3dQmvD5V0?rel=0&showsearch=0&autohide=2&autoplay=0&controls=1&fs=1&loop=0&showinfo=0&color=red&theme=light.
```

and this is the file where i have the error   (jquery.min.map.js:8)

i dont know where to start to search or what is the real error

can i have any advice?
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you viewing your page with https?

Comment: question solved, thank you for your time

Comment: `https` or `http`, nothing is causing any error in **chrome**. What's wrong???

Comment: its solved now, This function is added inside a project, the error was some security errors caused by the Other function, thank you for ur time